# manifest.json vs manifest.webmanifest

Tags: web-applications, manifest, progressive-web-apps

I'm developing an application using mongodb, Node.JS and PWA. In the first step of developing I don't know what is the difference between `manifest.json`
 and `manifest.webmanifest`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

#### November 2019 Update

The difference is mentioned in [MDN (Mozilla Developer Network)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Manifest):

> The .webmanifest extension is specified in the Media type registration section of the specification (the response of the manifest file should return Content-Type: application/manifest+json). Browsers generally support manifests with other appropriate extensions like .json (Content-Type: application/json).

You can read more details on: [Media Type Registration](https://w3c.github.io/manifest/#media-type-registration)

Answer (score 50):

There are no big difference rather than naming. Use whichever you prefer: `href="/manifest.webmanifest"` or `"/manifest.json"`. Just don't forget that MIME type has to be: `application/manifest+json` in both cases.

```html
<link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.webmanifest">
<link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">
```

Note that [spec says](https://www.w3.org/TR/appmanifest/) it should be `manifest.webmanifest`. And later it may be important because it is under heavy development.

For more info check:
[W3C](https://github.com/w3c/manifest/issues/689) and
[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Manifest)

Comment: I have seen the link you sent before I ask the question. The problem is that I can't understand the difference of them.

Comment: As I have understood it is under development and they considering is it worth to add some specific extension or not. So e.g why we have `.css` and `.html` files when it is usual text file why not `.txt`? Because it is more clear and reliable. I believe here is the same deal. `.webmanifest` only for clarification where it should be used, while syntacis will be 100% same as `.json`. But Is it realy worth to add specific extention? It is still not cleare because it may confuse some developers as we can clearly see now :)

Comment: hmm, I think they have some differences as you said it is confusing, but I don't know them.

Comment: I realy doubt they have. I beleive you can provide whatever name and whatever extention just it should match with `<link rel="manifest" href="manifest.webmanifest">` in header and should be in JSON format. So it can be `<link rel="manifest" href="myfile.mucustomextention">`

Answer (score 6):

Like mentioned in the other answers, there's not much of a difference in both.
But, according to [webhint.io](https://webhint.io/docs/user-guide/hints/hint-manifest-file-extension/?source=devtools), **it is recommended** to use `manifest.webmanifest`.

> `manifest-file-extension` warns against using non-standard file extensions for the [web app manifest](https://www.w3.org/TR/appmanifest) file.
>
> While the .webmanifest file extension is not enforced by the specification, nor is it required by browsers, using it makes it:
>
> - [easier to set custom server configurations](https://github.com/w3c/manifest/issues/346) for the web app manifest file
> - possible to benefit from [existing configurations](https://github.com/jshttp/mime-db/blob/67a4d013c31e73c47b5d975062f0088aea6cd5cd/src/custom-types.json#L85-L92)

This is also displayed as a tip in Microsoft Edge Browser Dev-tools in the issue panel (screenshot below)

[image: Screenshot of Edge Devtools]

Answer (score 0):

As said in other answers, a `.webmanifest` file is recognized as a simple JSON file by the editors.

But using the `.webmanifest` extension allows you to setup a specific process in your development tools (linting, deployment).

For example, you can configure VSCode editor to check your `.webmanifest` file against the [Web App Manifest JSON schema](https://json.schemastore.org/web-manifest-combined.json) and provide autocompletion.